# bokeh multiple plots into a gridplot

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm able to generate/show individual plots, but cannot seem to be able to aggregate multiple plots into a single gridplot. What am I doing wrong, thanks?

```
g = []
for item in basket:
    # sourcing and processing my data streams here
    # then moving to plotting the processed data into a single plot as below

    TOOLTIPS = [("(x,y)", "($x, $y)")]
    p = figure(tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,save",
               title=TITLE,x_range=x, 
               y_range=(<<my_y0_range_1>>,<<my_y0_range_2>>), 
               x_axis_label='time',y_axis_label='index',
               plot_width=1000, plot_height=450,toolbar_location="below",
               tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
    p.background_fill_color = <<mycolor>>
    p.line(x, y0, legend_label="values", line_width=1)

    p.extra_y_ranges = {"Vol": Range1d(start=<<my_y1_range_1>>,end=<<my_y1_range_2>>)}
    p.line(x, y1, legend_label="my 2nd Y axis", line_color="red",y_range_name="Vol")
    p.varea(x=x,y1=<<my_range_1>>,y2=<<my_range_2>>,alpha=0.3)
    p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Vol"), 'right')

    #show(p)                  <-- this works and displays the individual plot

    g.append(p)
# end/exit my for loop here

print (len(g))                <-- this prints out 3 in my test case
print (g)                     <-- [Figure(id='1001', ...), Figure(id='1066', ...), Figure(id='1131', ...)]

grid = gridplot(g)            <-- complains here
```

The exact error message I get is..

```
    grid = gridplot(g)
  File "\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bokeh\layouts.py", line 304, in gridplot
    for x, item in enumerate(row):
TypeError: 'Figure' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gridplot`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/layouts.html?highlight=gridplot#bokeh.layouts.gridplot) takes a list of lists (a list of rows), not a single 1d list. (Or if you really want, it does take a single 1d list, but you have to specify `ncols` in the call.)

Comment: Thanks, @bigreddot. Adding the ncols arg made the problem go away (and I want to use ncols in my gridplot spec). Could you help explain the situation as to what a list of rows means in the context. i.e., if I do not use ncols, I would have to specify which individual plots go in the first row, and which ones in the second row and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly (a grid is inherently two dimensions).